# Angular ngFor "Cannot convert object to primitive value"

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

i've just import a json file with some sample data and i would like to create a table of that. For the data i use an interface class OrderLineItems.ts, then i will import the file in the shopware Grid Component, which works well i guess. But when i just use console.log.
[shopware-grid.component.ts](https://github.com/jack20084/no-order-mgmt/blob/master/src/app/shopware-grid/shopware-grid.component.ts)

When i try to use the products property at the shopware-grid.component.html with ngFor i get the following convert Error.
[shopware-grid.component.html](https://github.com/jack20084/no-order-mgmt/blob/master/src/app/shopware-grid/shopware-grid.component.html)

```
core.mjs:6362 ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.mjs:3200:87)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2504:18)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2463:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2414:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11713:21)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:12793:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11488:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11748:13)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:12793:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11488:9)
```

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/jack20084/no-order-mgmt)

Comment: It does work, can you please check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-local-json-file-5tqqme)?

Comment: thank you very much. one point seems to be, that i´ve import the json data with * as test. When i correct this to your implementation, it works! Do you know why? 
BR NOrt